# Additive checks with jwt-auth in users_groups table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

In  Laravel 5.8 app using tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.0
I have users_groups table and I need for logged user for some controller to make check if inside of some group.
For this in routes/api.php I have :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth',  'prefix' => 'manager', 'as' => 'manager.'], function ($router) {
    Route::get('users_of_event_selection/{event_id}', 'API\ManagerController@users_of_event_selection');
    Route::post('add_user_to_event', 'API\ManagerController@add_user_to_event');
...

I app/Http/Controllers/API/ManagerController.php I added checks:

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => []]);
        $request           = request();
        $this->requestData = $request->all();

        $loggedUser= Auth::guard('api')->user();
        $userGroupsCount = UsersGroups
            ::getByUserId($loggedUser->id)
            ->getByGroupId([ACCESS_ROLE_ADMIN,ACCESS_ROLE_MANAGER])
            ->count();
        if($userGroupsCount == 0) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

    }
```

But

```
$userGroupsCount == 0
```

the code above does not work as I expected and my control's method returns valid data. I suppose I can make 
small function and to call it in top on any control's method, but if that ig good way? If jwt-auth has any way to extend 
additive checks ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have anybody make such additive checks? No ideas ?